# Is there an "ism" associated with Scientocracy?

Tags: single-word-requests

Scientocracy (to my understanding and as my intended meaning) is government by results, i.e., eschew policy debates to instead argue and then agree on metrics, run an experiment and then transition to whichever solution produces the best outcome as determined by the agreed upon metrics (of course, if cultural, climatic or other considerations make a new policy ineffective in a certain place, the policy should be revoked or adapted there).

My question is what is the 'ism' associated with this? Scientocracism isn't a word, and ends with racism, so that doesn't really work. Technocracy (a related, if more loaded term) has the same problem.

An example sentence would be: I believe in representative democracy, but I also believe in [] because while I think that we should be able to elect people to represent our interests - and fire them when they fail - I also believe in results.

Comment: When you searched for existing definitions and usage of "scientocracy", what did you find?

Comment: *Scientocracy* is a very rare word in English so I wouldn't use it (*technocracy* is much more common with a similar meaning, and it's no more loaded). And why would it have an ism? There's not a law that all English concepts must be named by a word ending in -ism. *Scientocracy* is the noun, just like *aristocracy* or *technocracy*. If you want to say you believe in it, you say "I believe in scientocracy".

Answer (score 1):

**Empiricism** (in the non-philosophical sense) might work. [Collins defines it as:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/empiricism)

> Empiricism is the belief that people should rely on practical experience and experiments, rather than on theories, as a basis for knowledge.

**Experimentalism** could work also. [MW defines it as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/experimentalism#:%7E:text=also%20%2D%CB%8Cspir%2D,specifically%20%3A%20instrumentalism)

> reliance on or advocacy of experimental or empirical principles and procedures